# Couldn't find Boot disk error while Installing Windows 7 using USB

Tags: windows-7, installation

I am getting problem while installing windows 7 on my single partition hard disk. I am using bootable USB drive for the installation. The error I get is "Setup was unable to create new system partition or locate an existing system partition. See the setup log files for more information". When I opened the setup log file(setuperr.log), it shows the error "Couldn't find boot disk on the BIOS based computer". Have anyone got this error before. Please help!!

More Info:

Boot Sequence:USB, Harddisk

System: Dell Inspiron 1545

Comment: Should probably be on SuperUser. If others agree, the question will be automatically migrated there for you. :-)

Answer (score 11):

I got this same error, setting the hard disk as 1st (and even removing the USB stick from the boot order) did not help. As far as I can tell, this is some interaction in the BIOS that prevents the win10 installer from thinking that the installation target drive is bootable, perhaps due to the particular USB key I was using (a USB 3.0 Kingston DataTraveler). I solved it by creating an "install partition" on the target disk using diskpart from the command line (shift+F10 in the installer):

```
> diskpart
diskpart> list disk
diskpart> select disk 0   # Choose the disk you want to install to
diskpart> clean           # will delete everything, hope you have backups!
diskpart> create partition primary size=100000 # size in MB
diskpart> create partition primary size=5000 # temporary install partition
diskpart> format fs=ntfs quick
diskpart> assign          # assigns a drive letter, it was D: for me
diskpart> active          # makes the install partition bootable
diskpart> exit
```

then copy the installer files from the USB key to the temporary partition:

```
c:\> xcopy c: d: /e /h    # /e for recursive with empty, /h for system files
```

and reboot, remove the USB key, and boot from the temporary install partition. The win10 installer will detect that the disk is bootable this time through & will let you install. When you're done with the installer you can remove the temporary partition and resize your main partition to take up the whole disk.

Comment: How can i know which drive is the temporary partition and which is usb?

Comment: This finally worked. Tried a lot of options, this is failsafe.

Comment: This also seems to work for Windows 10 (and a USB2 key which was causing the problem).

Comment: In diskpart, you might use `list volume` to know which letter is which partition. Also, note that xcopy arguments order are first origin and then destination.

Comment: Please How can I boot from the temporary install partition on my laptop Asus UX310U

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the Hard Disk as boot order 1 and USB as order 2. While the PC is booting hit F12 during the POST and select the USB drive.