# ASUS UX310U doesn't boot from the temporary install partition

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, partitioning, asus-laptop

I would like to install windows 7 on my laptop Asus UX310U after I follow the following steps that mentioned in this video [Solved: Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4ilMAAk1Q8) my laptop doesn't boot from the disk to continue the installation of Windows 7 and I got this photo 
[image]

Even though I copied all the content of USB flash (Lexar USB 3.0 32Gb) to a specific partition of disk C and typed active, The bottom line I followed all the steps but with no luck please could you help me to solve that problem 
the same steps that I followed here too 
[Couldn't find Boot disk error while Installing Windows 7 using USB](https://superuser.com/questions/320581/couldnt-find-boot-disk-error-while-installing-windows-7-using-usb?rq=1)

**How can I boot from the temporary install partition**
**I've just tired windows 10 the problem still the same**

Comment: Your hardware is NOT compatible with old Windows.

Comment: so there is no solution ?

Comment: The solution is to install a supported OS :)

Comment: which Is windows 10 am I wrong so there is no windows 7 please are you sure that there is no solution that helps me to install windows 7

Comment: When the manufacturer doesn't support older Windows and consequently doesn't publish drivers for it, users are on their own. The only (tiny) chance for installing Windows 7 in that machine is doing so in UEFI mode (=> using a USB stick made for that purpose), have a pre-prepared installation drive in GPT (Windows in UEFI mode strictly requires GPT), no actual partitions needed, the installer should take care of it, but the partitioning table must be GPT. Then good luck finding drivers. It's really a stupid way to waste time in my opinion.

Comment: I tried also windows 10 problem still the same

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, probably the USB installer itself. Try doing it with the official media creation tool, the default option if the ISO is downloaded in a Windows machine.

Comment: should I use PowerISO to create USB flash ?

Comment: Why use something else when there's an official tool for that purpose, and that purpose only? Rufus with the proper settings should work as well but any other tool will probably fail with the new non-standard Microsoft ISOs. That is likely the cause of your problems.

Comment: By the way, I used the same USB flash and I succeed to install windows 10 on another laptop

Comment: Thank you I will use Rufus and try to follow the same steps to see where is problem

Comment: Good for you but that means nothing. Or, if it means something, it only means the other PC is BIOS (or UEFI but booting in Legacy/CSM).

Comment: In this case, Please How can I install windows on my laptop Asus that not booting in Legacy/CSM

Comment: You don't want Legacy/CSM!!! Actually disable anything that mentions it in the firmware settings. Then all you need to have is a properly done USB installer (if using RUFUS then do NOT use the default options but change it to GPT/UEFI).

Comment: In Rufus, I am using MBR In partition scheme and target  System BIOS or UEFI-CSM, Am I on the right way?

Comment: No, that are exactly the settings I said shouldn't be used. You need to learn UEFI and its requirements.